Why does LSTM Model and FGSM Attack Implementation in TensorFlow: Shape Mismatch Errors occur when Sequential() call?
I'm working on a project to implement an FGSM (Fast Gradient Sign Method) attack on an LSTM model for stock price prediction using TensorFlow and Keras. Despite my efforts, I'm encountering persistent issues with tensor shape mismatches, and I'm trying to figure out what could possibly be wrong with the code.
I’ve created an LSTM model to predict stock prices and tried generating adversarial examples using the FGSM method. The training seems to proceed without issues, but when I attempt to generate adversarial examples and evaluate the model with this data, I encounter the following error:
Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().
Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

Arguments received by Sequential.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

test_predictions = model.predict(adversarial_test_data)
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().

The sample dataset filename "Stocks.zip" can be download via this link:
https://github.com/Headshake/Stock-Market-Analysis-using-LTSM.git
Here’s a summary of the relevant sections of my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Input
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def fgsm(input_data, model, true_labels, epsilon=0.01):
    input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
    true_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(true_labels, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(input_data)
        prediction = model(input_data)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(true_labels, prediction)
    
    gradient = tape.gradient(loss, input_data)
    adversarial_example = input_data + epsilon * tf.sign(gradient)
    
    # Print tensor shapes for debugging
    print(f"Input data shape: {input_data.shape}")
    print(f"True labels shape: {true_labels.shape}")
    print(f"Prediction shape: {prediction.shape}")
    print(f"Loss: {loss}")
    print(f"Gradient shape: {gradient.shape}")
    print(f"Adversarial example shape: {adversarial_example.shape}")
    
    return adversarial_example.numpy()

## Data Preparation ##
rootpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
folderpath = os.path.join(rootpath, './Stocks')

for file_name in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folderpath, file_name), usecols=['Date', 'Close'])
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        print('file:', file_name)
        
        data = df.filter(['Close'])
        dataset = data.values
        training_data_len = int(np.ceil(len(dataset) * 0.8))
        
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        scale_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

        # Create the training data set
        train_data = scale_data[0:int(training_data_len), :]
        x_train = []
        y_train = []

        for i in range(50, len(train_data)):
            x_train.append(train_data[i-50:i, 0])
            y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

        x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
        x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
        y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (y_train.shape[0], 1))

        # Build the LSTM model using Input layer
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
        model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(25))
        model.add(Dense(1))

        # Compile the model
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
        model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.2)

        # Generate adversarial examples for the training data
        adversarial_train_data = fgsm(x_train, model, y_train, epsilon=0.01)

        # Create the testing dataset
        test_data = scale_data[training_data_len - 50:, :]
        x_test = []
        y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
        for i in range(50, len(test_data)):
            x_test.append(test_data[i-50:i, 0])

        x_test = np.array(x_test)
        y_test = np.array(y_test)

        # Generate adversarial examples for the test data
        adversarial_test_data = fgsm(x_test, model, y_test, epsilon=0.01)

        # Ensure that the adversarial data has the correct shape
        adversarial_train_data = np.reshape(adversarial_train_data, (adversarial_train_data.shape[0], adversarial_train_data.shape[1], 1))
        adversarial_test_data = np.reshape(adversarial_test_data, (adversarial_test_data.shape[0], adversarial_test_data.shape[1], 1))

        # Evaluate the model with adversarial training data
        train_predictions = model.predict(adversarial_train_data)
        train_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((train_predictions - y_train) ** 2))
        print(f'Training RMSE with adversarial examples: {train_rmse}')

        # Evaluate the model with adversarial test data
        test_predictions = model.predict(adversarial_test_data)
        test_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((test_predictions - y_test) ** 2))
        print(f'Test RMSE with adversarial examples: {test_rmse}')

How to properly handle tensor shapes in TensorFlow/Keras to avoid shape mismatch errors?
Any insights into why the Sequential.call() method might be encountering an unknown rank shape error?
